# TROUBLE WITH Arrays and functions c++

Tags: c++, arrays, function

Basically water at certain temperatures has different specific weights which i set into 2 arrays depending on which units system you are using SI for metric and I for imperial. Im trying to figure out how to either make a function to use the user input temperature of the water to determine its corresponding specific weight or how to get the user to re input a value without starting over. Now ive got this thing to work if you input a standard temperature but i need to figure out how to get the user to re-input a temperature if they had previously put in an un-standard value.

Example:
  if you go through the proccess and select Y and SI and T and get to cout << " what is the temperature of water";
cin << T[1]; // also no idea why i put this into an array by itslef

if you input lets say 88 
the specific weight calculates to zero because thats not value in the temperature array, even though the value is obviously not suppose to be zero. Is there any way to allow the user to try again without closing and re starting this while process or somehow using a function or even getting the temperature to round to the closest standard value and just use that specific weight???
ps my programming skills are super basic (if you cant tell by my code)

any help would be appreciated, Thanks!

```
// this program will calculate the specific weight of water at any given temperature in either metirc or imperial and the reslutant force of the water in in tank


#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
#include<string>
#include<iomanip>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

// my sad attempt at trying to write a function

float match_temp_to_sw(float T[1]);

/*float match_temp_to_sw{
for(i=o; T[1]!=SI[i]; i++){
c = i+1;
x = SWSI[c];
}

}
*/



int main() {

    string units_system, units_sw, units_p, units_FR, a;
    string fluid;
    char pressure, pressure1;
    int calculate_specific_weight;
    char calculate_SW, calculate_FR;
    float specific_gravity, specific_weight, temperature;
    float pressureA;
    int i,c;
// these are count variables for the for loops to determine the specific                             weight of water at a specific temperature
    float x, area, height, FR;

// these are the values of the temperature and specific weight of water in metric and imperial units

    int SI[21] = {0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65,70,75,80,85,90,95,100};

    float SWSI[21]= {9.81,9.81,9.81,9.81,9.79,9.78,9.77,9.75,9.73,9.71,9.69,9.67,9.65,9.62,9.59,9.56,9.53,9.50,9.47,9.44,9.40};

    int I[19] = {32,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110,120,130,140,150,160,170,180,190,200,212};

    float SWI[19] = {62.4,62.4,62.4,62.4,62.3,62.1,62.0,61.9,61.7,61.5,61.4,61.2,61.0,60.8,60.6,60.4,60.1,59.8};
    int T[1];

    cout << fixed << showpoint;// setting the precision of the number of sigfigs
    cout << setprecision(2);

    cout << "Do you want to calculate the resultant force of water acting on a tanks surface?(Y or N)\n";

    cin >> calculate_FR;

    while(calculate_FR == 'Y') { // the outer most loop

// initialzing the string variable to zero so that way when you repeat this whole process they dont remember your previous input

        a = "NULL";
        units_system ="NULL";

// initializing the standard set of units that are going to be used   throughout the calculations

        while(units_system !="Imperial"&& units_system!="SI") {

            cout<< "what units system are you using Imperial or SI\n";
            cin>> units_system;
            cout<< "\nTherefore, you are using the "<<units_system<< " system\n" ;
        }

        fluid = "water";


        while (a!="SG" && a!="T") {

            cout << "\nDo you know the specific gravity(SG) or the temperature(T)?\n";
            cin >> a;
        }

        if(a == "SG") {

            cout << "\nWhat is the specific gravity of the water?\n";
            cin >> specific_gravity;
        }


        else if (a == "T") {
            cout << "\nWhat is the temperature of water\n";
            cin >> T[1];
        }


// if you are using the SI system the units for specific wieght will be kN/m^3

        if(units_system == "SI") {
            units_sw = " kN/m^3";
            units_p = " kPa";
            specific_weight = (specific_gravity *9.81);
            units_FR = "kN";

            if(a == "T") {


                if (T[1]== SI[0]) {
                    specific_weight =SWSI[0];
                }
                for(i=0; T[1]!=SI[i]; i++) {
                    c = (i+1);
                    specific_weight= SWSI[c];


                }
                if(T[1]!=SI[21]) {
                    cout << "You did not enter a standard value, and i dont know how to get you to reinput a proper value without restarting this program so please try again";
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }
// if you are using the imperial system the units for specific weight will be lb/ft^3
        else if(units_system == "Imperial") {
            units_sw = " lb/ft^3";
            units_p = " lb/ft^2";
            specific_weight = (specific_gravity *62.4);
            units_FR = "lb";

            if(a == "T") {

                if(T[1]== I[0]) {
                    specific_weight=SWI[0];
                }

                for(i=0; T[1]!=I[i]; i++) { // a for loop to determine the corresponding specific wieght to the user input temperature

                    specific_weight= SWI[i];

                }
            }
        }

        cout <<"\nTherefore, the specific weight of "<<fluid<<" is ";
        cout << specific_weight<< units_sw;

// i know this isnt in the right spot lol

//cout << "\n\nDo you want to calculate the specific weight of water at another temperature(Y or N)?\n";
//cin >> calculate_SW;

        cout << "\n\nWhat is the vertical height to the centroid of the shape you are analyzing\n";
        cin >> height;

        cout << "What is the area of the shape you are analyzing\n";
        cin >> area;

        FR = (specific_weight * height * area);

        cout << "\nThe resultant force acting on the tank you are analyzing is " << FR <<" " << units_FR;

        cout << "\n\nDo you want to calculate the resultant force of water at another temperature(Y or N)?\n";
        cin >> calculate_SW;

        while (calculate_FR == 'N') {

            cout << "\nYou do not want to complete anymore calculations";
            return 0;
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation of the shown code. The random indentation makes the shown code pretty much unreadable.

Comment: `cin >> a;`  -- Giving your variables 1-letter names makes the code harder to read, harder to understand, harder to debug, and easier to make a mistake.  Use more descriptive names.

Comment: For values that are not in your arrays you can *interpolate*. The easiest and coursest is to assume that your data points are connected by straight line segments; this is called linear interpolation. It looks like you have *parallel arrays*. It's usually simpler, less complex, to use an array of items where each item holds a group of related values. You can use `struct` to define a suitable item type.

Comment: You can use any good programmers' editor, or free stand-alone tools such as AStyle, to fix the indenting of your code. I used AStyle.

Comment: Note that in your function you are trying to access array SI[i], which is not declared in that function it is declared in the main thus you can't access it in your function you tried to write

Answer (score 0):

A `while` loop should solve your problem. See below:

```
else if (a == "T") {
    int temperature;
    cout << "\nWhat is the temperature of water\n";
    cin >> temperature;

    while (temperature <= 88) {
        cout << "Temperature should be greater than 88. Try again: ";
        cin >> temperature;
    }
    T[1] = temperature;
}
```

The `while` loop will either fall through or never execute once the temperature entered is greater than 88 in this case. This would allow you to continue entering incorrect temperatures, indefinitely, until a correct one is found without exiting the program and starting again.

You may want to define a global `const` variable to take the place of `88`-- depending on what your lower bound is on the temperature a user can enter--to make your code a bit easier to understand and edit in the future. Something like `const int MIN_TEMP = 88;` at the top of your code, in which case your `while` condition would look like this:

```
while (temperature <= MIN_TEMP) {
```

You could even define a function `getTemp()` with everything but the last statement in the above `else if` block that returns an `int` corresponding to a valid user-entered temperature.